# Can't create instance of jsPDF class - Error : « jsPDF » is undefined - IE11

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf

I know it's close to these posts :

> [jsPDF is not supported in remote server for IE-11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35593985/jspdf-is-not-supported-in-remote-server-for-ie-11)
>   
>   [I am generating a pdf file using jspdf library and I am getting the error "jspdf is not defined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32057559/i-am-generating-a-pdf-file-using-jspdf-library-and-i-am-getting-the-error-jspdf)

but since they are old unresolved topics, i'll up it here.

Here is my problem : I don't understand why I can't create a new instance of jsPDF. I'm using an existing library that I downloaded to be sure it was ok :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.0\webapps\jsPDF-1.3.2\jspdf.js"></script>
```

And I get my error here :

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
```

The call lacks one parameter but I figured it was not the source of the problem.

I tested on IE-11, and I can't change this (I mean I'm forced to get this working with IE, and with IE-8+ if possible - but sadly, I think it's impossible for IE-8 because it doesn't support totally html5 features).

If it is impossible to get jsPDF working with IE, do you have any other IE-compatible libraries that I could use to download a generated PDF file from styled html?

Thanks in advance for your help.

EDITs :
- tried shim, pointlessly.
- works perfectly in chrome.

Comment: so, the page is loaded using `file:///` - IE11 disabled javascript on locally loaded (by locally I mean using file:/// protocol) pages

Comment: oh right! i'll try this soon enough. Thanks for replying.