# How do i convert all the data in my webpage to a pdf and download it on the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

My task requires me to click a button on the webpage and download the data as a pdf file. Simply printing the webpage wont do as there are certain tabs which are visible only upon selection.The data source is readily available on the pagenameVM.js. I tried using jsPDF but that works only for a certain div in the page.I need to write the all the required data into the pdf and then download it.
 Is it possible?

Comment: try priniting page and save as pdf file

Comment: Yes it's definitely possible. With enough coding knowledge you can custom print anything you want from a page. However it's hard to answer your question directly without seeing some code. Can you please post some? Otherwise any answers will just be taking a shot in the dark.

Comment: `I tried ...` did you? perhaps you did it wrong

Comment: Have you tried using TCPDF ot mPDF?

Comment: var doc=new jsPDF(); this line shows exception" 'jsPDF' is undefined" when IE 8 is used in Document mode Emulated ,however when in debugger i alter it to IE10 it works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44719019/cant-create-instance-of-jspdf-class-error-jspdf-is-undefined-ie11

Comment: @JaromandaX  this is the issue i am facing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44719019/cant-create-instance-of-jspdf-class-error-jspdf-is-undefined-ie11

Comment: so, the problem you are facing is that jsPDF isn't working in IE11 when you load a page using `file:///` protocol schema? easy, tell IE11 that it's safe to run javascript in a locally loaded page

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for the response.I tried doing that it did not work !!Is there any other way i can create a pdf from my C# code and download it into the browser upon the click of a button..

Comment: @HemantRajpoot that would not serve the purpose as all the data is not visible at once in the page